# Having options on both side of a menu

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner at HTML, and I was trying to make a web page to gain experience. I wanted to create this menu but I want it to have options on both sides of it. Just like the HOME, ABOUT ME, etc. options is on the right side, I want similar options on the left side too but am not able to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: The web page]

The HTML code:

```
<div id="menu">
    <nav class="navl" style="justify-content: right">
        <ul>
            <li class="navulli">
                <a href="C:\Users\vivek\Desktop\html-css-course\LegendsOfTime\LOT_Home.html">
                    Home
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

The CSS code:

```
#menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-size: cover;
    justify-content: right;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.navl {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150%;
    line-height: 10px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    display: flex;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.6;
    margin: 0px;
}
.navulli {
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 0.7s all;
    font-family: Century Gothic, CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    place-items: left;
    margin: 0px;
}

.navulli:hover {
    opacity: 0.4;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 30px;
    justify-content: right;
    font-size: calc(1rem + 0.2vw);
    margin-top: 0px;
}
i {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    justify-content: right;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: calc(1rem + 0.5vw);
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use a [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) with `justify-content: space-between;`

```css
nav {
  background: silver;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
    <li>six</li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks you again, Hope you have a good one.